# Rails advanced search query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a database with Lab models. I want to be able to search them using multiple different methods.

1. I chose to use one input field and separate query into words array:

   ```
   search = search.split(/[^[[:word:]]]+/).map{|val| val.downcase}
   ```
2. I use Acts-as-taggable gem so it would be nice to include those tags in search to:

   ```
   tag_results =  self.tagged_with(search, any: true, wild: true)
   ```
3. For methods down below it seemed to be necessary to use:

   ```
   search = search.map{|val| "%#{val}%"}
   ```
4. Sunspot seemed also a great way to go for full-text search so

   ```
   full_text_search = self.search {fulltext search}
   full_text_results = full_text_search.results
   ```
5. I decided to go also with simple database query searching for a Lab name:

   ```
   name_results = self.where("LOWER(name) ILIKE ANY ( array[?] )", search)
   ```
6. Lastly I need all of the results in one array so:

   ```
   result = (tag_results + name_results + full_text_results).uniq
   ```

It works perfectly (what I mean is that the result is what I expect) but it returns a simple array and not `ActiveRecord::Relation` so there is no way for me to use method like `.select()` or `.order()` on the results.

I want to ask is there is some better way to implement such search? I was searching for search engines but it seems like there is nothing that would fit my idea.

If there is not - is there a way to convert an array into ActiveRecord::Relation? (SO says there is no way)

Comment: You can also just use Enumerable's `select` and `sort` or `sort_by` on the result array

Comment: @diego.greyrobot wich is slow as hell :) OP is totally correct in wanting to convert it to AR

Comment: What exactly is a `tag_result` or other result?

Comment: Can you provide the sql for each query?

Comment: B Seven - tag_results is just an array. .tagged_with is a method provided by Acts-as-taggable gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering this one:

> is there a way to convert an array into ActiveRecord::Relation? (SO
>   says there is no way)

You can convert an array ob ActiveRecord objects into ActiveRecord::Relation by fetching ids from array and querying your AR model for objects with these ids:

```
Model.where(id: result.map(&:ids)) # returns AR, as expected.
```

It is the only way I am aware of.

Comment: That is correct. The answer was in the SO thread I checked just one mouse scroll below :) Thank you for bringing this up. Can you comment of the way that I use to perform the search? Are there any gems that I should be aware of that can help me simplify this?

Comment: @Ancinek I can see you're sunspot, which I never used (I have only used elasticsearch), so can not provide any valuable input on that. I say measure it somehow if you can. As long as it is resource-efficient and not slow - it is just fine..